# How to get all facebook events?

Tags: django, facebook, events

I'm building a django app and I'm interested if there is a way to get all the newest/popular events from facebook.

I want to get their title, location, description etc.

EDIT:

For the solution in the answer bellow to be successful i'll need the access token. It can't be done with the app token. Also I don't need to search through events but retrieve them sorted by popularity.

Since i'm using django facebook for now i can get my users friends events (in which they are participating). Is there another way to retrieve them through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Look for the headline "Searching":

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event
```

You need an access token for it, but i guess an app access token will do:

```
$app_access_token = APPID . '|' . APPSECRET;
```

The app access token is valid as long as you don´t change the id and secret of the app (will most likely never happen).

EDIT:

If you take a look at the FQL table of the events, there is no field for the "popularity":

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

...so i guess you mean sorting by "most attending people". But you wrote "all the newest/popular events from facebook", so that means all events and not only those of the logged in user and his friends. The only way to get the events in that case is the solution i presented above.

If you want to get the Events of the user, FQL would be the correct way, i guess:

```
SELECT name,description,location,attending_count from event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()) ORDER BY attending_count DESC
```

This gives you all events of the user, sorted by the number of attending people.